# Tip users reputation

Tags: feature-request

I passed by some really good answers and I wouldnt mind giving them 50 of my reputation. Will there be a "tip" feature that will giveaway my rep to a person? I know its possible for the Original Poster to give out a bounty, but it would be great for the occasional reader to tip as well.

Comment: duplicate of bounties.